# Infinite redirect when moving an app service for an app and an app service for its identity server to azure front door from standalone app services

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-front-door, duende-identity-server

We have two app services that make up our app - app.mydomain.com and an identity server (duende identity server) on auth.mydomain.com.  After setting up azure front door, and creating an endpoint for app.mydomain.com and one for auth.mydomain.com and standing up a secondary server for each as another origin (so now, then app.mydomain.com has two app services in different regions as origins for it, and auth.mydomain.com also has two app service origins in different regions as well), I have an infinite redirect loop between app.mydomain.com and auth.mydomain.com.  When app.mydomain loads, it immediately redirects to app.mydomain.com/bff/silent-login because it somehow doesn't think it's logged in, even though the cookie is there.  Which then redirects to auth.mydomain.com/connect/authorize, which then redirects to app.mydomain.com/signin-oidc and then the site does a get on app.mydomain.com/bff/silent-login-callback to process that response.  But then it's redirected to app.mydomain.com/bff/login for some reason right away, which sends to auth.mydomain.com/connect/authorize, which then redirects to app.mydomain.com/signin-oidc again.  Then it loads app.mydomain.com like it should, but then it still somehow thinks it's not logged in and kicks off this entire progression again.  Over and over.  Has anyone encountered this before?  How did you get around it?  Our application setup worked fine as single app services before we stood up front door and put them behind it, with secondary services for each.